# Three.js renderer activate GC really often

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, three.js

I'm building a web based game and i'm experiencing a very high garbage collector activity when rendering. Three.js r68

Sometimes up to ~8mb collected 8 times per second ! (says chrome debugger)

I'm monitoring the WebGLRenderer info and they are all fixed geom, vertex, programm, etc ...

[image: stats]

I'm also removing all the app logic that is done and letting the rendering alone. And this is still happening

```
G.StateView.prototype.render = function (renderer) {
    if (this.active) {
        //this.update();
    }
    renderer.render(this.getRenderScene(), this.getRenderCamera());

};
```

What is the normal behaviour of the GC for this kind of setup ? What will influence the memory usage over time of the renderer ?